# C++ virtual destructor & vtable

Tags: c++, polymorphism, vtable

I have some specific questions on virtual destructors and vtable.

Suppose I have the following code:

```
class Base
{
public:

    virtual ~Base();

};

class Child : public Base
{
public:

    ~Child();
};
```

Questions:

1. Where is the vtable stored? Is it always in the base class and all sub-classes simply keeps a pointer to it?
2. Adding a virtual method only increases the sizeof(class) by 8 bytes right? (assume 64bit system) How about base class if it stores the table?
3. Creating an instance of type Child via the new operator then delete ... will the Base destructor be called? (I'm asking because Child class's destructor isn't virtual ... does that mean it only affects sub-class of Child?).

Comment: *1 and 2:* implementation-defined. *3:* Yes.

Comment: I assume you meant `Child` to actually be a child-class of`Base`?

Comment: 1. (a) Each class must have its own vtable, otherise the technique cannot work. (b) There is really no such thing as 'in the class'.  2. is therefore irrelevant. 3. Child's destructor *is* virtual if the base class's is.

Comment: If the base class destructor is virtual, then destructors of all derived classes are also virtual - regardless of you writing `virtual` or `override` or not; that's optional but does not change the fact that the derived dtor *is* virtual.

Comment: @DeiDei -- formally, not "implementation defined", but "implementation specific". In the language definition, "implementation defined" means that the implementation must document what it does.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The explanation below assumes that virtual dispatch implementation used by the compiler is based on virtual tables.

1. Each class with virtual methods (declared or inherited) has its own virtual table. If a subclass overrides a virtual member function in the base, a pointer to the overriding function is placed in the class's vtable; otherwise, a pointer to base class implementation is kept in place.
2. Adding the first virtual function increases the size of the class *instance* by the size of vtable pointer. Virtual functions after the first one do not add to the size of the instance.
3. Since `~Base` is virtual, the `~Child` is virtual as well, even though `virtual` keyword is omitted. In case of an override, `virtual` keyword is optional.

Comment: I dont understand why answer based on assumptions (logical assumptions to be true), not origin of question. Main language between programmers is code, and code negate assumption

Comment: @JacekCz It's pretty clear from everything else OP writes that he has forgotten to add `: public Base` in the `Child`.

Comment: "a pointer to the overriding function is placed in the copy" What is meant by "copy" in this context?

Comment: @JordanMelo I'm not crazy about the term 'copy' in this answer. It isn't a copy, it's just another vtable.

Comment: @CaptainGiraffe I still don't understand your question. What is a 'vtable pointer to the subclass'? What does it point to?

Comment: @CaptainGiraffe There's nothing in this answer that says the vtable is or isn't reused if there are no overrides. RTTI provides another reason for a separate vtable. Does that answer your question?

Comment: @EJP, I was interpreting the statement to mean that child->vptr ==  base->vptr unless an override was made.  I was misunderstanding what I read. Due to my misreading, my objections makes no sense. Thank you for you patience.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out that I forgot to write the ": public Base" part which I have added. I am curious why after adding the first virtual method, the sizeof(class) doesn't not get increased further?

Comment: @ChaoSXDemon Because all instances of the same class share a single instance of virtual table, which by its nature cannot be modified. The table itself grows, but the pointer size is the same, regardless of the size of the table to which it points.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight thanks for that note. So that's why it's implementation dependent on where that table actually gets stored right? So even the base class would have a pointer to that table ... which I'm guessing one option is to store it along with all the static variables?

Comment: @ChaoSXDemon Yes, and yes. Another option is to store tables in the so-called "text segment", with code and string literals.

Answer (score 2):

> Creating an instance of type Child via the new operator then delete ... will the Base destructor be called?

Not in the original question code, because you don't have `Child` inheriting from `Base`.

Assuming that's a mistake, and we fix it, then `~Base` would be called when you destroy a `Child` even if it weren't virtual, just because the base-class sub-object is destroyed as part of the normal destruction sequence.

The reason for virtual destructors is so you can delete a `Child` *via* a `Base *` and still have `~Child` invoked correctly.

Eg, with:

```
struct Base { ~Base(); };
struct Child: Base { ~Child(); };

struct VBase { virtual ~VBase(); };
struct VChild: VBase { ~VChild(); };
```

this works for both hierarchies:

```
template <typename Derived>
void test_static() {
  Derived d;
}
test_static<Child>();  // ~Child then ~Base invoked when d is destroyed
test_static<VChild>(); // ~VChild then ~VBase invoked when d is destroyed
```

but this only works with a virtual destructor:

```
template <typename Derived, typename Base>
void test_dynamic() {
  std::unique_ptr<Base> p(new Derived);
}
test_dynamic<Child, Base>;  // only ~Base invoked when p destroyed
test_dynamic<VChild,VBase>; // ~VChild then ~VBase invoked as before.
```

---

As for the *vtable* questions, it's an implementation detail whether one exists, and if so where it is, and you don't need to worry about it.

Answer (score 1):

Every class with virtual methods (declared/inherited) has its own virtual table(vtable). When a virtual method (any, not just the destructor) is declared virtual, all overrides of that method in derived classes are automatically virtual. The compiler also adds _vptr at the beginning of any such classes having virtual methods. This _vptr will be filled when the class's object is created and will point to the vtable of that class. A virtual destructor is treated the same way as any other virtual function. In your example since ~Base is virtual, ~Child will be virtual as well.

Suppose if you do:

```
Child *child = new (class Child);
delete(child);
```

Here, child->_vptr would be pointing to Child's vtable. So during delete, ~Child will be called first & followed by ~Base (in the reverse order of construction).

Alternately if you do,

```
Base *base = new (class Child);
delete(base);
```

Here, base->_vptr would be pointing to Child's vtable. So during delete, ~Child will be called first & followed by ~Base from the vtable.

In gdb, we can verify this _vptr by running this command,

```
"info vtbl base" or "print *base"
```